# Can we have 2 forms in the same Angular2 component

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

i am new to Angular 2 and would like to know that can we have 2 forms in a single angular 2 component. Below is what my form.component.html looks like.

```
<div>
 <span>Forms Using ngModel Directive</span>
  <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(form.value)">
  <div>
    <label>Firstname:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" ngModel>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Lastname:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" ngModel>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Street:</label>
    <input type="text" name="street" ngModel>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Zip:</label>
    <input type="text" name="zip" ngModel>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>City:</label>
    <input type="text" name="city" ngModel>
  </div>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<pre>
 {{form.value | json}}
</pre>

<h4>Submitted</h4>
<pre>    
 {{value | json }}
</pre>

<span>Same Form using ngModelGroup & ngModel Directive(Notice Difference      in the JSon)</span>
  <form #form1="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(form1.value)">
  <div ngModelGroup="name">
    <label>Firstname:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname1" ngModel>
    <label>Lastname:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname1" ngModel>
  </div>
  <div ngModelGroup="address">
    <label>Street:</label>
    <input type="text" name="street1" ngModel>

    <label>Zip:</label>
    <input type="text" name="zip1" ngModel>

    <label>City:</label>
    <input type="text" name="city1" ngModel>
  </div>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<pre>
 {{form1.value | json}}
</pre>

<h4>Submitted</h4>
<pre>    
  {{value | json }}
</pre>
```

If you see above i have two forms inside the same component. Now when ever i enter values into the respective fields i can see the JSON being created appropriately ... but when i submit either of the forms the submitted JSON is created in both forms identically even though the other form may be empty. Is this due to the fact that an HTML page can contain only one form without any kind of ajax involved. Could anyone please explain this to me .... below is a link to plunk for this.

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZoCOzlCNa82ugbYiXyjK?p=preview

Comment: I think so its not an anything with angular 2 you need to create two request and call each form onSubmit with its unique function

Comment: its better to separate it to 2 components. its easyer to test and is a cleaner.

Comment: might be the solution you want  https://plnkr.co/edit/yzMbR85Pliw1AMcqiYyE?p=preview

Comment: @mayur : Thanks for the reply ... i checked your code but it doesnt seem to work as intended .... i am generating the JSON data as it is being entered and in your code that doesnt seem to happen ... i was playing around with it but couldnt get it to work i would want it to i.e.`each JSON should be able to submit independently ...`

Answer (score 3):

It works as expected.

You forms have individual values, but you are saving result to the same variable `value`

```
submit(form) {
  this.value = form; 
}
```

And prints it

```
<pre>    
  {{value | json }}
</pre>
```

I.e. submitting one form does not affect the other. It affects only common variable `value`.

If you need to separate processing, then use different submit functions.

If you want to use the same function, then you need to differ passed value.